# Can an Azure Function App access an on-premises resource via a VPN or Hybrid connection?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, hybrid-cloud, azure-hybrid-connections

Function Apps that run on a Dynamic service plan are restricted in certain ways (as expected).

Is it possible somehow to call an on-premises resource (via a VPN or Hybrid Connection) from a Function App in a Dynamic service plan?

Comment: Could you possibly share what prevents your using an App Service Plan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would you be able to consider using the Azure Service Bus? Functions have support for adding messages to the servicebus queue (read more: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/functions-bindings-service-bus/) and then in your on-prem environment you'd process the servicebus queue.

This is what I've done with provisioning logic for Web Jobs and other cloud-to-onprem environments previously, while I've yet to try it with Functions - but as per the article mentioned Functions should be able to process the messages to the SB queue.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can confirm that this method will work, I just completed such a proof of conce pt for my company. We've got an Azure Function set up on a serviceBusTrigger for a topic/subscription that reads some data, transforms it, and puts it on another queue that subsequently gets read by an on-premise application.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement, i have achieved it with Azure function app with Dynamic plan using HCM and SFTP refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70582498/1820783).